# JavaScript returns "is not a function" error yet the method is listed in response in Firebug

Tags: php, javascript, json, zend-framework, json-rpc

I am getting the following error in Firebug when loading a web page:

```
redirect.processBrowser is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
url = redirect.processBrowser(JSON.stringify(browserInfo));
```

The response as seen in Firebug is as follows:

```
{"transport":"POST","envelope":"JSON-RPC-2.0","contentType":"application\/json","SMDVersion":"2.0","target":"\/json-rpc.php","services":{"processBrowser":{"envelope":"JSON-RPC-2.0","transport":"POST","parameters":[{"type":"object","name":"json","optional":false}],"returns":"string"}},"methods":{"processBrowser":{"envelope":"JSON-RPC-2.0","transport":"POST","parameters":[{"type":"object","name":"json","optional":false}],"returns":"string"}}}{"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid Request","data":null},"id":null}
```

The javascript for the code is as follows:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.zend.jsonrpc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/browserDetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            browserInfo = {
                "screen_width": screen.width,
                "screen_height": screen.height,
                "color_depth": screen.colorDepth,
                "url": document.URL,
                "user_agent": navigator.userAgent,
                "browser_name": BrowserDetect.browser,
                "browser_version": BrowserDetect.version,
                "platform": BrowserDetect.OS
            };

            redirect = jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({url: '/json-rpc.php'});

            url = redirect.processBrowser(JSON.stringify(browserInfo));

            window.location.replace(url);
        });
    </script>
```

The jsonrpc.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Define path to the application directory
defined('REFERRAL_SYSTEM_ROOT') || define('REFERRAL_SYSTEM_ROOT', realpath('/system'));
defined('REFERRAL_PUBLIC_ROOT') || define('REFERRAL_PUBLIC_ROOT', realpath('/public'));

require_once REFERRAL_SYSTEM_ROOT . '/some_file.php';

/**
 * Zend Application
 **/
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application($_ENV["REFERRAL_ENVIRONMENT"], REFERRAL_SYSTEM_ROOT . '/config/application.ini');

$application->getBootstrap();

require_once 'Browser.php';

// Instantiate server, etc.
$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$server->setClass('Browser');

if('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
    $server->setTarget('/jsonrpc.php')
           ->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

    // Grab the SMD
    $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

    // Return the SMD to the client
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $smd;
}

$server->handle();
```

As you can see from the response, processBrowser is seen by the ZEND_JSON_RPC server, yet I am getting the "is not a function" response. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** -> 4/26/2012 @ 4:25 PM EDT

While the function *processBrowser()* DOES exist, it is part of the *Browser* class as defined in *Browser.php*, the call *jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({url: '/json-rpc.php'})* is evidently not receiving a proper response. I still do not know why.

Comment: You're getting the error message because it's not a function.  Try a `console.log(redirect)` to see for yourself.

Comment: While the function DOES actually exist, it appears that the JavaScript is not getting back a proper result when jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({url: '/json-rpc.php'}); is called.

Comment: Are you saying FireFox is *wrong*?  It doesn't exist if your JSON response is malformed, or if one of your JS files fails to load or parse.

Comment: Lee, of course I'm not saying that Firefox is wrong. I'm _saying_ that there **is** a public function that I've defined in the `Browser` class in PHP named `processBrowser()`, but that it is not getting loaded properly by JavaScript. The issue I'm having is _**why**_ is JS **NOT** getting the proper response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. Try to remove the line "`header('Content-Type: application/json');`". It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I took the json that you said was from the firebug console and jsonlint it.

Here is the result:
Parse error on line 35:
...g"        }    }}{    "error": {
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

You have the closing bracket to the whole response before the error section.  I am not sure what is generating the response but it needs to be removed from there and place it at the end.

This is the json corrected:

{
    "transport": "POST",
    "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "SMDVersion": "2.0",
    "target": "/json-rpc.php",
    "services": {
        "processBrowser": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [{
                "type": "object",
                "name": "json",
                "optional": false}],
            "returns": "string"
        }
    },
    "methods": {
        "processBrowser": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [{
                "type": "object",
                "name": "json",
                "optional": false}],
            "returns": "string"
        }
    }
 {
    "error": {
        "code": -32600,
        "message": "Invalid Request",
        "data": null
    },
    "id": null
    }
    };